# WOEID to Lat, Long

Tags: google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude

I'm making a simple webapp where the user inputs WOEID and plots the location on the map. I'm currently using Google Maps API and as far as I know it does not support WOEID plotting, so I'm trying to find a simple way to get Lat/Lng coordinates from a WOEID. I know Yahoo's PlaceFinder should work but it was designed for Lat/Lng to WOEID and not the other way around.

Is there a simple way to get Lat/Lng from a WOEID?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Lat/Long from Yahoo directly.

The [docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/guide/api_docs.html) show that the lat/long is returned in the XML response.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<place yahoo:uri="http://where.yahooapis.com/v1/place/2507854" xml:lang="en">
  <woeid>2507854</woeid>
  <placeTypeName code="7">Town</placeTypeName>
  <name>Trenton</name>
  <country type="Country" code="US">United States</country>
  <admin1 type="State" code="NJ">New Jersey</admin1>
  <admin2 type="County" code="">Mercer</admin2>
  <admin3/>
  <locality1>Trenton</locality1>
  <locality2/>
  <postal/>
  <centroid>
    <latitude>40.21777</latitude>
    <longitude>-74.759361</longitude>
  </centroid>
  <boundingBox>
    <southWest>
      <latitude>40.183868</latitude>
      <longitude>-74.819519</longitude>
    </southWest>
    <northEast>
      <latitude>40.248291</latitude>
      <longitude>-74.728798</longitude>
    </northEast>
  </boundingBox>
</place>
```

The thing your interested in is probably the `centroid` element.

Comment: The links used in this answer are now deprecated, but you could still query w/ a woeid via [query.yahooapis.com](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select+*+from+geo.places+where+woeid=%272507854%27)